# Trying to make method wait for internal event handling finished

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm new in C# async/await and facing some issues while trying to work with async method.
I have a collection:

```
private IList<IContactInfo> _contactInfoList
```

And an async method:

```
public async Task<IList<IContactInfo>> SelectContacts()
{
    _contactInfoList = new List<IContactInfo>();
    ContactsSelector selector = new ContactsSelector();
    selector.ShowPicker();

    selector.ContactsSelected += (object sender, ContactsSelectorEventArgs e) =>
    {
        this._contactInfoList = e.Contacts;                
    };

    return _contactInfoList;
}
```

Contact selector is a popup user control which allows to select some contacts from phone and after the "OK" button tapped it fires `ContactsSelected` event. I need to get the selected contacts list from the event arguments `e.Contacts` and return that list in above mentioned `SelectContacts()` async method. And here is the issue: My method is already returning empty list `_contactInfoList` before the `ContactsSelected` event has finished his job. I know that async/await even doesn't matter in this case and this issue will be exist in usual method, but I just need to make that method to wait event handling result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do here is convert an event style of asynchronous programming to a task style of asynchronous programming.  The use of a `TaskCompletionSource` make this fairly straightforward.

```
public static Task<IList<IContactInfo>> WhenContactsSelected(
    this ContactsSelector selector)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IList<IContactInfo>>();
    selector.ContactsSelected += (object sender, ContactsSelectorEventArgs e) =>
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(e.Contacts);
    };
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Now that we have a method that returns a task with the result that we need, the method that uses it is quite straightforward:

```
public Task<IList<IContactInfo>> SelectContacts()
{
    ContactsSelector selector = new ContactsSelector();
    selector.ShowPicker();

    return selector.WhenContactsSelected();
}
```

There are a few things to note here.  First, I removed the instance field; that seems like a bad idea here.  If `SelectContacts` is called several times it would result in the two fighting over that field.  Logically if you do need to store the list it should be a local variable.  Next, there are no `await` uses here, so the method shouldn't be marked as `async`.  If you wanted to `await` the call to `WhenContactsSelected` then feel free to add `async` back in, but as of now I see no real need for it.

Comment: @Servy, why are you using `TrySetResult` and not `SetResult`? Would it be a good idea to add `try/catch` inside the event handler, and call `tcs.SetResult` inside `try`, and `tcs.SetException` inside `catch`?